# Footnote-like custom function for org-roam-insert

Tags: org-mode, doom, org-roam

I am trying to make a custom function for org-roam which inserts footnote-like links in the current note.

The idea is to insert links on this way

```
The logistic regression [fn:20200612000001]...

* Footnotes

[fn:20200612000001] [[file:20200612000001-definition_logistic_regression.org][Logistic regression]]
```

and the linked file has the form

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: 20200612000001
:END:
#+TITLE: Definition Logistic Regression
```

I just copy-pasted the original `org-roam-insert` function and hacked it a little to insert the footnote. The code is here https://gist.github.com/maikol-solis/ed149c16cff16a55492d1acba8c12025.

However, after a couple of times using it, emacs crashes completely.  I think that is caused by this function because this has never happened before.

I used `gdb` to follow the crash and this is the output:

```
Thread 1 "emacs-gtk" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
gui_produce_glyphs (it=0x7fff82fc3650) at xdisp.c:29925
29925         struct font *font = face->font;
(gdb) next
handle_sigsegv (sig=11, siginfo=0xc201f0 <sigsegv_stack+7152>, arg=0xc200c0 <sigsegv_stack+6848>) at sysdep.c:1876
1876    {
(gdb) next
1882      if (!fatal && !pthread_equal (pthread_self (), main_thread_id))
(gdb) next
1886      if (!fatal && stack_overflow (siginfo))
(gdb) next
1890      deliver_fatal_thread_signal (sig);
(gdb) next

Thread 1 "emacs-gtk" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fc45ddc1170 in raise () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function raise,
which has no line number information.
[Thread 0x7fc44567f700 (LWP 28923) exited]
[Thread 0x7fc4477fe700 (LWP 28922) exited]
[Thread 0x7fc447fff700 (LWP 28921) exited]
[Thread 0x7fc44df97700 (LWP 28920) exited]

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

I appreciate any help to solve this issue.
Best.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code and everything is working now. Around this line https://gist.github.com/maikol-solis/ed149c16cff16a55492d1acba8c12025#file-org-roam-insert-footnote-L47

I added this

```
(find-file target-file-path)
(setq target-vector-id
      (car (org-roam--extract-ids target-file-path)))
(kill-current-buffer)
```

I still don't know why occurred the crash, but it works.